# Applying padding to anchors inside unordered list only applies to anchor

Tags: html, css

I have a simple navigation bar that I want to style mobile-friendly, which means making the links as big as possible.

I figured I'd just apply padding to the anchor nested inside my `<li>` tags, but the padding only appears when I hover the anchor. Any idea how can I get this to always show, and also expand the surrounding elements accordingly (the `<li>`,`<ul>`,`<div>`) is appreciated.

```css
/********************************
 IMPORTS (breakpoints, colors...)
********************************/

/********************************
BREAKPOINT MIXINS
********************************/

/********************************
COLORS
********************************/

/********************************
GENERAL
********************************/

html {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  html {
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
}
/********************************
BANNER
********************************/

#banner {
  margin: 1em 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("../img/banner/420.png");
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  #banner {
    background-image: url("../img/banner/767.png");
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #banner {
    background-image: url("../img/banner/992.png");
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #banner {
    background-image: url("../img/banner/1200.png");
  }
}
/********************************
NAVBAR
********************************/

#navbar {
  background-color: #913D88;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navbar {
    border-radius: 1em;
  }
}
#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#navbar ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19%;
  /* TODO FIGURE OUT DROPDOWNS

   &:hover > ul {
    display: block;
   }
   ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
    background-color: $primary-color;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    li {
     font-size: 1.1em;
     font-weight: 400;
     display: block;
    }
   }

   */
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  #navbar ul li {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navbar ul li {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
}
#navbar ul li a {
  padding: 1em;
}
#navbar ul li a:visited,
#navbar ul li a:link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #491f45;
  background-color: #c371ba;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>ZIC Knjižnica</title>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="banner"></div>

  <div id="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">IJS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">knjižnica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">zaloga</a>
    <!--<ul>
      <li><a href="#">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">elektronske revije</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">katalog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">baze podatkov</a></li>
     </ul>-->     
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">storitve</a>
    <!--<ul>
      <li><a href="#">medknjižnična izposoja</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">fotokopirnica</a></li>
     </ul>-->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ENG</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

sorry about the weird formatting of html, no idea what's going on there. tried to sort it out with the tidy function, nothing happened. Also my css is generated from sass, figured I'd post css to make the snippet work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: See: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but if it's only to see the padding all the time then:

```css
/********************************
 IMPORTS (breakpoints, colors...)
********************************/

/********************************
BREAKPOINT MIXINS
********************************/

/********************************
COLORS
********************************/

/********************************
GENERAL
********************************/

html {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  html {
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
}
/********************************
BANNER
********************************/

#banner {
  margin: 1em 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("../img/banner/420.png");
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  #banner {
    background-image: url("../img/banner/767.png");
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #banner {
    background-image: url("../img/banner/992.png");
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #banner {
    background-image: url("../img/banner/1200.png");
  }
}
/********************************
NAVBAR
********************************/

#navbar {
  background-color: #913D88;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navbar {
    border-radius: 1em;
  }
}
#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#navbar ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19%;
  /* TODO FIGURE OUT DROPDOWNS

   &:hover > ul {
    display: block;
   }
   ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
    background-color: $primary-color;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    li {
     font-size: 1.1em;
     font-weight: 400;
     display: block;
    }
   }

   */
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  #navbar ul li {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navbar ul li {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
}
#navbar ul li a {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #913D88;
}
#navbar ul li a:visited,
#navbar ul li a:link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #491f45;
  background-color: #c371ba;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>ZIC Knjižnica</title>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="banner"></div>

  <div id="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">IJS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">knjižnica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">zaloga</a>
    <!--<ul>
      <li><a href="#">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">elektronske revije</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">katalog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">baze podatkov</a></li>
     </ul>-->     
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">storitve</a>
    <!--<ul>
      <li><a href="#">medknjižnična izposoja</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">fotokopirnica</a></li>
     </ul>-->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ENG</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

The reason you didn't see it before was that no background was set for the `<a>` elements. I simply added a `background-color` setting to the "standard" `a` selector.

Comment: I would also like the <li> and <ul> and <div> height to stretch to encompass the anchors, but this is a step forward =)